# Is there an FFT that uses a logarithmic division of frequency?

Tags: audio, signal-processing, fft, logarithm

Wikipedia's [Wavelet article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet#Comparisons_with_Fourier_Transform_.28Continuous-Time.29) contains this text:

> The discrete wavelet transform is also less computationally complex, taking O(N) time as compared to O(N log N) for the [fast Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform). This computational advantage is not inherent to the transform, but reflects the choice of a logarithmic division of frequency, in contrast to the equally spaced frequency divisions of the FFT.

Does this imply that there's also an FFT-like algorithm that uses a logarithmic division of frequency instead of linear?  Is it also O(N)?  This would obviously be preferable for a lot of applications.

Comment: It's an interesting idea.  I'm not sure how useful though: would the waveforms with the logarithmic frequencies form a complete basis and if not, what use are they?  (Not to say it's not useful, I really mean I'm not sure.)

Comment: I was assuming it would be similar to the FFT, but with the bins in the result logarithmically spaced.  An audio spectrum analyzer, for instance, would benefit from this because it would have higher resolution at low frequencies and lower resolution at high frequencies (http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/doc/suse/suse9.0/userguide-9.0/sound_audacity_spectrum.png), and the higher speed of computation would allow it to refresh at a much faster rate or provide greater resolution overall.

Comment: Now that I understand it better, a complex Morlet wavelet transform would probably do what I was imagining, for a spectrum analyzer, at least.

Comment: @endolith: or [constant-Q transform](http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~anssik/cqt/) http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/6266/29

Comment: Very intersting, thanks.  I also found the wikipedia page on the constant-Q transform to be useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_Q_transform

Comment: Hi think that the answers to *"How can I compute a log-spaced power spectrum?"* at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/129/how-can-i-compute-a-log-spaced-power-spectrum give very good complements.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.  Yes.  No.

It is called the Logarithmic Fourier Transform. It has O(n) time.  However it is useful for functions which decay slowly with increasing domain/abscissa.

Referring back the wikipedia article:

> The main difference is that wavelets
>   are localized in both time and
>   frequency whereas the standard Fourier
>   transform is only localized in
>   frequency.

So if you can be localized only in time (or space, pick your interpretation of the abscissa) then Wavelets (or discrete cosine transform) are a reasonable approach.  But if you need to go on and on and on, then you need the fourier transform.

Read more about LFT at http://homepages.dias.ie/~ajones/publications/28.pdf

Here is the abstract:

> We present  an exact and analytical expression  for the Fourier transform of  a function that has been  sampled  logarithmically.  The procedure  is  significantly more  efficient  computationally than the fast Fourier  transformation  (FFT)  for  transforming  functions or measured  responses which decay slowly with increasing  abscissa value. We illustrate  the proposed method with an example from electromagnetic geophysics, where  the scaling is often such that our logarithmic Fourier  transform  (LFT) should  be  applied.  For  the example  chosen, we  are able  to obtain results  that  agree with  those from  an FFT to within  0.5 per cent  in  a  time  that  is  a  factor of 1.0e2  shorter. Potential  applications of  our LFT in geophysics include conversion of  wide-band electromagnetic  frequency  responses  to  transient  responses,  glacial  loading  and  unloading, 
>   aquifer  recharge problems,  normal mode  and earth  tide  studies in  seismology,  and  impulsive shock wave modelling.

Comment: Ohhh, so the time-domain signal needs to be sampled logarithmically, too?  (Meaning the samples are not equally spaced in time?)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: After reading up on this I think this algorithm is not really useful for this question, I will give a description anyway for other readers.

There is also <strike>the Filon's algorithm</strike> a method based on Filon's qudrature which can be found in <strike>Numerical Recipes</strike> this [PhD thesis][1].
The timescale is log spaced as is the resulting frequeny scale.

This algorithm is used for data/functions which decayed to 0 in the observed  time interval (which is probably not your case), a typical simple example would be an exponential decay.

If your data is noted by points (x_0,y_0),(x_1,y_1)...(x_i,y_i) and you want to calculate the spectrum A(f) where f is the frequency from lets say f_min=1/x_max to f_max=1/x_min
 log spaced.
The real part for each frequency f is then calculated by:

A(f) = sum from i=0...i-1 { (y_i+1 - y_i)/(x_i+1 - x_i) * [ cos(2*pi*f * t_i+1) - cos(2*pi*f*t_i) ]/((2*pi*f)^2) }

The imaginary part is:

A(f) = y_0/(2*pi*f) + sum from i=0...i-1 { (y_i+1 - y_i)/(x_i+1 - x_i) * [ sin(2*pi*f * t_i+1) - sin(2*pi*f*t_i) ]/((2*pi*f)^2) }

[1] Blochowicz, Thomas: *Broadband Dielectric Spectroscopy in Neat and Binary Molecular Glass Formers.* University of Bayreuth, 2003, Chapter 3.2.3

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want, you need to measure different time Windows, which means lower frequencies get update least often (inversely proportional to powers of 2).

Check FPPO here:
https://www.rationalacoustics.com/files/FFT_Fundamentals.pdf

This means that higher frequencies will update more often, but you always average (moving average is good), but can also let it move faster. Of course, if plan on using the inverse FFT, you don't want any of this. Also, to have better accuracy (smaller bandwidth) at lower frequencies, means these need to update much more slowly, like 16k Windows (1/3 m/s).

Yeah, a low frequency signal naturally travels slowly, and thus of course, you need a lot of time to detect them. This is not a problem that math can fix. It's a natural trade of, and you can't have high accuracy a lower frequency and fast response.

I think the link I provide will clarify some of your options...7 years after you asked the question, unfortunately.